# Handling events internally in server

Tags: api, server, backend

I'm trying to make sense of how to handle events in my server in a neat way.

I'm creating a Whatsapp chatbot that receives messages via webhooks at a certain endpoint on my server. It doesn't seem right to me to handle all logic at that endpoint, so what I'm thinking of doing is passing the data to another endpoint (something like '/messages/inbound') where the logic for inbound messages is handled. Then if a response needs to be made, I send the payload to a different endpoint, say '/messages/outbound'. I then need to interface with a database and perform different actions on it. I'm thinking of creating separate endpoints for each action on the database.

I call these endpoints internally on my server, which I imagine shouldn't be inefficient, because they're hosted on the same computer. But is this the correct way of going about doing this? I have little experience with backend design and don't know if there's perhaps a recommended practice for dealing with different events, or if what I'm suggesting doesn't make sense altogether.

Comment: Are you suggesting that your web service sends another HTTP request to itself at a different URL?     Why not split the logic into separate methods and call those instead?     Having processes use any kind of remote/network communication for what sounds like can be achieved using ordinary function/method calls within the same process, sounds like an enormous and unnecessary overhead, which seems very unlikely to achieve anything useful

Comment: @BenCottrell I see. I just didn't know if it might make more sense to modularize logic across different endpoints, but thinking about it now, using functions for handling different actions achieves the exact same thing with substantially less complexity. Thanks for the reassurance.